java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class
I have the following Java method:
@Bulkhead(name = "getToken", type = Bulkhead.Type.THREADPOOL)
@TimeLimiter(name = "getToken")
@CircuitBreaker(name = "getToken", fallbackMethod = "fallbackRequestException")
public ResponseEntity<Resources> getByTokenPayload(HttpHeaders headers, String url) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        ResponseEntity<Resources> result = service.getByTokenResource(headers, url);
    }).thenApply(result -> {
        return result;
    });
}

I added fallback method like this:
  private CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<?>> fallbackRequestException(HttpHeaders headers, String paymentHandleToken, Throwable e) {
    // Create a body with error details
    Map<String, Object> errorBody = new HashMap<>();
    errorBody.put("error", "Fallback triggered due to an exception");
    errorBody.put("message", e.getMessage());
    errorBody.put("paymentHandleToken", paymentHandleToken);
    errorBody.put("timestamp", Instant.now());

    ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(errorBody, headers, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

    // Return a CompletableFuture with the ResponseEntity
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(responseEntity);
  }

When I get exception I get error:
    org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException: Cannot locate recovery method
        at org.springframework.retry.annotation.RecoverAnnotationRecoveryHandler.recover(RecoverAnnotationRecoveryHandler.java:78) ~[spring-retry-2.0.6.jar!/:na]


2024-10-03T18:09:06.165Z ERROR 1 --- [service] [nio-8180-exec-5] c.a.p.c.e.w.h.CommonControllerAdvice     : Caught unexpected exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class com.test.Resources (java.util.HashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.test.Resources is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.LaunchedClassLoader @f6f4d33)
        at com.test.TransactionDetailsService.getDetails(Service.java:212) ~[!/:0.0.1]

Do you know how I can fix this issue? Looks like I have to return CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<?>> but this result casted as a result.

The method's return type and that of the fallback obviously don't match. One is CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Resources>>, the other is effectively CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<HashMap<String, Object>>>. That mismatch is causing the issue. Can you change the method's return type to CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<?>> and see if that solves the issue?

hm... as far as I can see I have already  private CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<?>> fallbackRequestException(HttpHeaders headers, String paymentHandleToken, Throwable e) Maybe you mean I need to change it for the main method?

Indeed. When calling the endpoint from unit tests you won't be able to extract the value as a Resources instance anymore, unless you check the HTTP status code first and then cast the value.


It's important to remember that a fallback method should be placed in
the same class and must have the same method signature with just ONE
extra target exception parameter.
https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3

Apparently your methods have different signature.
public ResponseEntity<Resources> getByTokenPayload

private CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<?>> fallbackRequestException


I also just noticed a difference in the second parameter - a URL for the method itself, and a token for the fallback method. The types are the same so there won't be an error in the server code, but the "token" in the fallback response will probably be wrong.
